# How to get information on hidden rows from Google Sheet API without Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using the Google Sheets API V4 to retrieve its data in JSON like below. That includes all rows, even the ones currently not shown in the Spreadsheet UI because of a filtering in one of the columns.

Is there a way to get only the shown rows or information whether a row is hidden or not?

The Google Apps Script allows such data retrieval using i.e. the .hiddenByFilter Method (see https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/using-google-sheets-filters-in-add-ons ). However, I am not able to include that in my API Query whatsoever.

```
$.getJSON("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + SpreadsheetID + "/values/Color1!A2:Q?key=<MY_API_KEY>", function(data) {

// data.values contains the array of rows from the spreadsheet. Each row is also an array of cell values.
    $(data.values).each(function() {
      var location = {};
      location.title = this[2];
      location.latitude = parseFloat(this[10]);
      location.longitude = parseFloat(this[9]);
      location.institution = this[3];
      //location.hidden = <?>;
      locations.push(location);
    });
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) endpoint. Then filter `sheets/data/rowData/values` using [`sheets/data/rowMetadata/hiddenByUser`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#DimensionProperties) field client side.

Comment: Thanks! But I am struggling on how exactly to build my link to get that information. I can use the filters as point separated fields, right? Where do I have to filter in the get request? `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/<Spreadsheet ID>/values/Color1!A2:Q?key=<MY_API_KEY>` I guess would have to replace the `values` with my fields but that isn't working.

Comment: @phlp No you can't directly get the filtered data from the server. I'm suggesting  workaround: getting all the data and filter it client side based on `sheets/data/rowMetadata/hiddenByUser` in resulting response.

Comment: Perfect thanks. Just for clarification if anyone else reads this: the attribute would be called `hiddenByFilter` and not `hiddenByUser` (at least in this case) and only appears in the Tuples where it holds true (the other tuples do not contain it at all - compared to show false what I would have expected). Thank you!

Comment: @phlp If that solves your problem, consider accepting the answer.